# Handed Java Program

Tags: java

Hi can you please clear my doubt for the below program. the output is giving as 2 7 but as per my understanding it is 2,6 why the go method is calling one more extra time and count is incrementing as seven.

```
class Handed { 
    int state = 0; 
    Handed(int s) { 
        state = s; 
    } 

    public static void main(String... hi) { 
        Handed b1 = new Handed(1); 
        Handed b2 = new Handed(2); 
        int t1 = b1.go(b1); 
        int t2 = b2.go(b2); 
        System.out.println(t1 + " " + t2); 
        //System.out.println(b1.go(b1) + " " + b2.go(b2)); 
    } 

    int go(Handed b) { 
       if(this.state == 2) { 
          b.state = 5; go(this); 
       } 
       int t3 = ++this.state; 
       return t3;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is doing +1 at the

```
int t3 = ++this.state;
```

first time when the you call

```
go(this)
```

Then

```
this.state
```

is 6. Then you doing

```
int t3 = ++this.state;
```

again after the IF statment

Then this.state is 7

Comment: thanks i understood. in eclipse go(this) is getting called after count is 6 without checking if condition hence i got doubt.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `b2.go(b2);`, inside the go method both the variables `b` and `this` are same. So `go(this)` will increment `state` once and after that it again comes back to `int t3 = ++this.state;` line and increments `state` again.

Answer (score 0):

`++this.state` is executed twice , once in `go(this)` and once more after returning.

Comment: why it is executed once after count is 6. the method should return the value right.please explain.

Comment: The variable 'state' is incremented to 6 in the method call go(this),
after returning that value is not returned instead the control flows through the code to increment the state variable again and return the incremented value i.e., 7.

Answer (score 0):

The expression ++this.state increments the state by 1. So it gets 7.

Answer (score 0):

When you call "go" on b2, "go" is called twice because when state = 5, the if statement triggers. This causes the state to become 6 in both the variable you passed and the Handed you called the method from.

"go" is called again from the second statement in the if block, but since the state is not 5, you only return 6 + 1, which is 7.